# how to show a post on a custom detail page not single.php in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want show a post detail on a custom detail page not single.php. I know we use get_permalink() function for a post detail.
But what will be the permalink if I want to show it on custom detail page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom post type and use

```
echo post_permalink( $ID );
```

OR
Simply put the ID of the custom detail page into get_permalink()

Reference:
[POST PERMALINK CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_permalink)